# Animate a property back and forth (without jumping to the end)

Tags: animation, nativescript

I am using the following code to "zoom" a page in and out.

```
const doEffect = args => {
    const screen = args.object.page.getViewById('mainScreen')
    screen.animate({
        scale: {
            x: isSettingsShown ? 1 : .75,
            y: isSettingsShown ? 1 : .75
        },
        duration: 2000    
    })
    isSettingsShown = !isSettingsShown
}
```

There is a toggle button on the page that updates the `isSettingsShown` variable. However when I toggle the var before the animation has ended, it "jumps" to the end of the animation. Can I prevent this from happening? I would like to start the animation from the last position it was at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing the animation or retaining the state of animation is still an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3439) at the moment.

You may still be able to do this natively by operating on the nativeView's [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer?language=objc) (iOS) / [Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator) (Android).

Comment: Well one of the reasons I'm using NS is I don't know about native development unfortunately :). Thanks for the answer!